# Ubuntu Dual Screen Using Virtual Machine - AMD GPU

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, virtualbox

I've been searching online and reading tutorials and etc about how to make my ubuntu VM dual screen(x86_64). I have first tried to run these commands:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

which gave me the ouput of:

```
sudo: aitconfig: command not found
```

I then googled the output and followed these instructions that I tells me to install my ATI drivers onto my ubuntu.

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-5-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh ati-driver-installer-11-5-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo aticonfig -f --initial --adapter=all
sudo reboot
```

It all works well until I input sudo apt-get -f install which gives me the following output:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up fglrx (2:8.850-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/aticonfig is already managed     by x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf.
dpkg: error processing fglrx (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle:
fglrx-amdcccle depends on fglrx; however:
Package fglrx is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing fglrx-amdcccle (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-dev:
fglrx-dev depends on fglrx; however:
Package fglrx is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing fglrx-dev (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error     from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error     from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
fglrx
fglrx-amdcccle
fglrx-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At this point, I don't know what to do since running:

```
gksudo amdcccle
```

For the record, I have 3D acceleration turned on. The following is my GPU for my VM

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics     Adapter
```

Any Help on how I can make my VM dual screen with Ubuntu would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual Box can provide graphics output to multiple **virtual** monitors. These can either be configured as separate application windows, or can be directed to separate attached physical monitors when in seamless or fullscreen mode.

This feature is independent of the physically attached graphic card and can **not** be achieved by installing proprietary drivers to your virtual machine. Doing so is not recommended, as usually the VM has no direct access to the physical graphics adapter (unless you configured experimental PCI passthrough mode).

To enable multiple monitors we can define a monitor count of up to 8 for any virtual machine in the *Settings -> Display* from Virtual Box Manager:

[image]

After that we are able to configure these virtual monitors from the "*System Settings ->  Displays...* in Ubuntu:

[image]

All monitors will have the name **VBX** as they are virtually provided from Virtual Box. Which monitor is represented will also be shown in a corresponding coloured box in the virtual window.

Untick the Option *"Mirror Displays"* in case you want to display different applications on them.

After that we will have two Virtual Box windows numbered `:1` and `:2` where each can have a different geometry:

[image]

<sup>Virtual Box on host 12.04 amd64 running a single instance of a guest Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 displayed on two virtual monitor windows</sup>

Comment: I was using this method for dual screen before you posted this but what I also want to add for people who are having this issue is to turn on "steamless". This will allow you to drag applications across screens which is turned on by Host + L. That was what I ultimately looking for. Thanks for your detailed answer.